# The specified URL cannot be found. POST PHP 10 or more data

Tags: php, iis, http-status-code-404

Im trying to add data to our database using a form (see below)

[image]

[image]

I'm using Ajax to pass data to PHP.

Here's how it looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"../process/saveanndata2", 
        type:"POST",
        data:data,
        success:function(data){
        if(data == 'success'){
            window.focus();
            $(".status_1").html('Successfully saved!');
            $(".status_1").effect('pulsate','slow');
            $(".status_1").css('color','green');
            $("#saveann").attr('disabled','disabled');
            $("#add-payment").removeAttr('disabled');
            opener.document.fad.refresh_me.value='1';                            
         }
        },
        error: function(err,resp){
            $(".status_1").html('Error');
            $(".status_1").css('color','red');
            console.log(err+" "+resp);
            }
        });
```

the form is dynamically added per "+" sign button on the far right of the table.

Here's the string from the form data.

```
crop_cd1=0276&acres1=2.00&rate1=2&total1=4.00&crop_cd2=0275&acres2=4.00&rate2=5&method2=FU&total2=20.00&crop_cd3=0213&acres3=2.00&rate3=14&method3=FU&total3=28.00&crop_cd4=0811&acres4=2.2&rate4=1&method4=FU&total4=2.20&crop_cd5=0277&acres5=2.00&rate5=1&method5=FU&total5=2.00&crop_cd6=0276&acres6=2.00&rate6=5&method6=FU&total6=10.00&crop_cd7=0274&acres7=2.00&rate7=2&method7=FU&total7=4.00&crop_cd8=13SP&acres8=12.00&rate8=4&method8=FU&total8=48.00&crop_cd9=0259&acres9=1&rate9=2&method9=FU&total9=2.00&total_widthdrawn=120.20&id=9&mpid=344415922157&action_cd=DL&source_cd=GW&type=Diverter&owner_id=7961243&diverter_id=1234580&year=2011&use_cd=AG
```

Here's the ../process/saveanndata2

[image]

Every time I add more than 7 rows of data I always get this error (see above) I even analyzed the HTML file line by line to see if I have an attribute like `name='name'` but didn't find any. also disabled `post_max_size` on php.ini config.

I would really appreciate any help! I've been experiencing the problem for a long time.

Comment: How are you preparing the `data` variable?

Comment: What is the full URL showing when you get a 404?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose  data = $("#form").serialize();

Comment: @aynber can't show the full url for security reason (it's stupid right?) but it should look like. https://samplesite.com/process/saveanndata2
you know this link works if you just simply go there. no error 404.

Comment: @LexDacs why does your URL have a `..` in front?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose the front-end is folder below saveanndata2. 

process/saveanndata2.php
process/html/save_anndata.html

Comment: @LexDacs are you able to fix this issue, I am facing similar issue